# Pyspark join dataframe based on function

Tags: python, pyspark

I have 2 dataframes that look like that

networks

```
+----------------+-------+
|    Network     | VLAN  |
+----------------+-------+
| 192.168.1.0/24 | VLAN1 |
| 192.168.2.0/24 | VLAN2 |
+----------------+-------+
```

flows

```
+--------------+----------------+
|  source_ip   | destination_ip |
+--------------+----------------+
| 192.168.1.11 | 192.168.2.13   |
+--------------+----------------+
```

Ideally I would like to get something like this

```
+--------------+----------------+-------------+------------------+
|  source_ip   | destination_ip | source_vlan | destination_vlan |
+--------------+----------------+-------------+------------------+
| 192.168.1.11 | 192.168.2.13   | VLAN1       | VLAN2            |
+--------------+----------------+-------------+------------------+
```

Unfortunately the flows dataframe does not contain the subnetmask. What I have tried so far without pyspark

1. Get a distinct list of subnets (in this example [24])
2. For every subnet and source_ip compute the network `ipaddress.ip_network('{}/{}'.format(ip,sub), strict=False)`
3. Search if that subnet exists in dataframe "networks" and return VLAN otherwise return empty string

I tried to do a similar approach with pyspark but it does not work as well as I think there might be better ways of doing it?

```
def get_available_subnets(df):
    split_col = split(df['network'], '/')
    df = df.withColumn('sub', split_col.getItem(1))
    return df.select('sub').distinct()

def get_vlan_by_ip(ip, infoblox, subnets):
    for sub in subnets:
        net = ipaddress.ip_network('{}/{}'.format(ip,sub), strict=False)
        if net:
            search = infoblox.filter(infoblox.network == str(net))

            if not search.head(1).isEmpty():
                return search.first.vlan
    return hashlib.sha1(str.encode(ip)).hexdigest()

subnets = get_available_subnets(infoblox_networks_df).select('sub').rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()


short = flows_filtered_prepared_df.limit(1000)


partial_vlan_func = partial(get_vlan_by_ip, infoblox=infoblox_networks_df, subnets=subnets)
get_vlan_udf = udf(lambda ip: partial_vlan_func(ip), StringType())

short.select('source_ip', 'destination_ip', get_vlan_udf('source_ip').alias('source_vlan')).show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method completely avoids the use of `udf`, leveraging `split` and `slice`, but perhaps there is a better way. The benefit of this approach is that it directly leverages the bits present in the subnet mask and that it's written purely in `PySpark`.

Context for the solution: IP addresses can be split and masked by the subnet. This means that `8, 16, 24, 32` tell you which parts of the IP matter - this motivates the division by 8 and using the resulting column to slice the IP address `ArrayType` column once it's split from its original `StringType`.

NB: `pyspark.sql.functions.slice` will work in newer version of `PySpark >= 2.4`, some older ones need to use `f.expr("slice(...)")`.

The setup:

```
flows = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1, "192.168.1.1", "192.168.2.1"),
    (2, "192.168.2.1", "192.168.3.1"), 
    (3, "192.168.3.1", "192.168.1.1"), 
], ['id', 'source_ip', 'destination_ip'] 
)
networks = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1, "192.168.1.0/24", "VLAN1"),
    (2, "192.168.2.0/24", "VLAN2"), 
    (3, "192.168.3.0/24", "VLAN3"), 
], ['id', 'network', 'vlan'] 
)
```

Some pre-processing:

```
networks_split = networks.select(
    "*",
    (f.split(f.col("network"), "/")[1] / 8).cast("int").alias("bits"),
    f.split(f.split(f.col("network"), "/")[0], "\.").alias('segmented_ip')
)
networks_split.show()
+---+--------------+-----+----+----------------+
| id|       network| vlan|bits|    segmented_ip|
+---+--------------+-----+----+----------------+
|  1|192.168.1.0/24|VLAN1|   3|[192, 168, 1, 0]|
|  2|192.168.2.0/24|VLAN2|   3|[192, 168, 2, 0]|
|  3|192.168.3.0/24|VLAN3|   3|[192, 168, 3, 0]|
+---+--------------+-----+----+----------------+

networks_masked = networks_split.select(
    "*",
    f.expr("slice(segmented_ip, 1, bits)").alias("masked_bits"),
)
networks_masked.show()
+---+--------------+-----+----+----------------+-------------+
| id|       network| vlan|bits|    segmented_ip|  masked_bits|
+---+--------------+-----+----+----------------+-------------+
|  1|192.168.1.0/24|VLAN1|   3|[192, 168, 1, 0]|[192, 168, 1]|
|  2|192.168.2.0/24|VLAN2|   3|[192, 168, 2, 0]|[192, 168, 2]|
|  3|192.168.3.0/24|VLAN3|   3|[192, 168, 3, 0]|[192, 168, 3]|
+---+--------------+-----+----+----------------+-------------+

flows_split = flows.select(
    "*",
    f.split(f.split(f.col("source_ip"), "/")[0], "\.").alias('segmented_source_ip'),
    f.split(f.split(f.col("destination_ip"), "/")[0], "\.").alias('segmented_destination_ip')
)
flows_split.show()
+---+-----------+--------------+-------------------+------------------------+
| id|  source_ip|destination_ip|segmented_source_ip|segmented_destination_ip|
+---+-----------+--------------+-------------------+------------------------+
|  1|192.168.1.1|   192.168.2.1|   [192, 168, 1, 1]|        [192, 168, 2, 1]|
|  2|192.168.2.1|   192.168.3.1|   [192, 168, 2, 1]|        [192, 168, 3, 1]|
|  3|192.168.3.1|   192.168.1.1|   [192, 168, 3, 1]|        [192, 168, 1, 1]|
+---+-----------+--------------+-------------------+------------------------+
```

Finally, I `crossJoin` and filter on the slice based on the `bits` of my mask, such as:

```
flows_split.crossJoin(
    networks_masked.select("vlan", "bits", "masked_bits")
).where(
    f.expr("slice(segmented_source_ip, 1, bits)") == f.col("masked_bits")
).show()
+---+-----------+--------------+-------------------+------------------------+-----+----+-------------+
| id|  source_ip|destination_ip|segmented_source_ip|segmented_destination_ip| vlan|bits|  masked_bits|
+---+-----------+--------------+-------------------+------------------------+-----+----+-------------+
|  1|192.168.1.1|   192.168.2.1|   [192, 168, 1, 1]|        [192, 168, 2, 1]|VLAN1|   3|[192, 168, 1]|
|  2|192.168.2.1|   192.168.3.1|   [192, 168, 2, 1]|        [192, 168, 3, 1]|VLAN2|   3|[192, 168, 2]|
|  3|192.168.3.1|   192.168.1.1|   [192, 168, 3, 1]|        [192, 168, 1, 1]|VLAN3|   3|[192, 168, 3]|
+---+-----------+--------------+-------------------+------------------------+-----+----+-------------+
```

Exactly the same approach can be done for `destination_ip`, such as:

```
flows_split.crossJoin(
    networks_masked.select("vlan", "bits", "masked_bits")
).where(
    f.expr("slice(segmented_destination_ip, 1, bits)") == f.col("masked_bits")
).show()
+---+-----------+--------------+-------------------+------------------------+-----+----+-------------+
| id|  source_ip|destination_ip|segmented_source_ip|segmented_destination_ip| vlan|bits|  masked_bits|
+---+-----------+--------------+-------------------+------------------------+-----+----+-------------+
|  1|192.168.1.1|   192.168.2.1|   [192, 168, 1, 1]|        [192, 168, 2, 1]|VLAN2|   3|[192, 168, 2]|
|  2|192.168.2.1|   192.168.3.1|   [192, 168, 2, 1]|        [192, 168, 3, 1]|VLAN3|   3|[192, 168, 3]|
|  3|192.168.3.1|   192.168.1.1|   [192, 168, 3, 1]|        [192, 168, 1, 1]|VLAN1|   3|[192, 168, 1]|
+---+-----------+--------------+-------------------+------------------------+-----+----+-------------+
```

Finally, you either join the resulting two tables together on `source_ip` and `destination_ip` (since you have the `vlan` information attached as required), or you merge the previous two steps together and `crossJoin` and `filter` twice.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Genius! Thanks. 15x faster than the pandas implementation I have

Comment: hi, one issue I see is when the IP does not match with any of the networks it will not show in the join. How could I return an empty vlan field instead?

Comment: hi @Chris - this is not lost during the join (as this is a `crossJoin`) but rather after you filter using `where()`. This has an easy fix - remove the `where()` and use the `f.expr() == f.col()` statement inside the `where()` clause (let's call it `x`) to create a new column with `f.when(x, f.col("vlan")).otherwise(f.lit("NO VLAN"))`

Comment: do you mind modifying your answer? If I understand correctly I remove ```where()``` then add the ```when().otherwise()``` expression instead?

Comment: got that working. There is a problem with the bits calculation since ```10.19.24.0/23``` and ```10.19.26.0/23``` for the ip ```10.19.29.132``` will produce 2 entries is it is calculated to 2 bits

Comment: Ahh - I see how that can be a problem - `/23` corresponds to `255.255.254.0` netmask, which means that your `VLAN` host can be in the range `10.19.24.1 - 10.19.25.254`. The implementation above only works for `8, 16, 24, 32` subnets off the shelf. In which case, the solution would need to be rewritten to mask on byte level fully so that you recompute IPs to binary using `f.bin()` (don't forget to `f.lpad()`) and for example, `/23` subnet becomes `11111111.11111111.11111110.00000000` (23 `1`s). That way you can fully mask on byte level to make this work for all subnet implementations.